# How do I access and set the value of a LiveData Object from ROOM to a single View

Tags: kotlin, mvvm, data-binding, android-room

I have already sent an instance of a user data object to a local ROOM database to cache some data included in the Firebase sign in flow on loginFragment.kt

```
val firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser
        firebaseUser?.let {
            // here we get access to some of the data provided by firebase auth and pass it to a new user table in the local db
            //this should avoid having to call this data again later on for the profile.
            val uid = firebaseUser.uid
            val userName = firebaseUser.displayName.toString()
            val email = firebaseUser.email.toString()
            val photoUrl = firebaseUser.photoUrl.toString()
            val emailVerified = firebaseUser.isEmailVerified
            val userEntity = UserEntity(0,uid,userName,"Not Set","Not Set",0,0, email,photoUrl,emailVerified)
            viewModel.insertNewUser(userEntity)

        }
```

Now I'd like to access this data from the object via 1 query in my DAO.

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM user_local_data_table LIMIT 1")
 fun getUserDataLive(): LiveData<UserEntity>
```

Then we return the live data in the repo

```
    val getUserDataLive:LiveData<UserEntity> = userDatabaseDAO.getUserDataLive()
```

This is where I get stuck. Not sure where to go from here to get this data into the view model. Im using view binding in the xml text views bound to the read only properties in my view model

```
  val userEntity: LiveData<UserEntity>
    get()= _userEntity
val userId: LiveData<String>
    get() = _userId
val userName : LiveData<String>
    get() = _userName
val userFirstName : LiveData<String>
    get() = _userFirstName
val userLastName : LiveData<String>
    get() = _userLastName
val score : LiveData<Double>
    get() = _score
val userEmail : LiveData<String>
    get() = _userEmail
val emailVerified : LiveData<Boolean>
    get() = _emailVerified
```

And I also have the fields here but this is also part of where I am stuck.

```
    private var _userEntity = MutableLiveData<UserEntity>()
private val _userId : MutableLiveData<String> by lazy { MutableLiveData<String>() }
private val _userName : MutableLiveData<String> by lazy { MutableLiveData<String>() }
private val _userFirstName : MutableLiveData<String> by lazy { MutableLiveData<String>() }
private val _userEmail : MutableLiveData<String> by lazy { MutableLiveData<String>() }
private val _userLastName : MutableLiveData<String> by lazy { MutableLiveData<String>() }
private val _emailVerified : MutableLiveData<Boolean> by lazy { MutableLiveData<Boolean>() }
private var _score = MutableLiveData<Double>()
```

Is it possible to access the data from the LiveData userEntity that is passed from the database into the repository? I was hinted at using map but feel like there must be a more simple way to present these few data sets into a view with text views waiting for that data.

I should note I've been stuck on this for a few days and almost want to just write a query for each column in the user table. Though that would be a lot of code. All the examples I see return a LiveData list or flow for a recycler view, I just need one objects data if that makes any sense.
Or should I just make a recycler view with 1 object in it? Seems counterintuitive.
Example of the lab i am following:
[Android Room with a View - Java](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view#8)

[Learn advanced coroutines with Kotlin Flow and LiveData](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/advanced-kotlin-coroutines?hl=en#0)

Comment: Does your ViewModel have access to the repository?

Comment: yes, I can access values and functions from the repository through the view model

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using transformation.map in the repo and using the domain model to observe changes.

in my repo:

```
 val userList:LiveData<List<User>> = Transformations.map(database.userDao.getUserListLive(1)){
    Log.i(logTag,"Return list of live user data limit 1 id of current user ")

    it.asDomainModel()
}
```